# How to remove Bootstrap styling in angular SPA?

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, single-page-application

I am trying to modify an ASP.Net Core 2.2 Angular SPA stylings. I see that certain webpack:///./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_reboot.scss is generated at runtime.

I want to define the styles myself so I removed the reference to bootstrap module in "styles": [..] section in angular.json and added referce to my own css file like this -

```
"styles": [
          //"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles/HTML5_CSS3_Responsive_Style.css"
        ],
```

The problem is this gives me an error -

> Cannot Get /

I tried placing my css file in the node modules directory of bootstrap.css file and it still doesn't work. Am I missing something? I there any other place where the reference needs to be removed.

This is angular 6(I think) SPA with asp.net core 2.2.

Comment: The css file should be in assets folder . Otherwise it wont be copied by webpack to dist

Answer (score 0):

Very silly mistake from my side. The css had a reference to an image which was missing